# Why is it that when i make an image a link it creates a little black line to the right of it?

Tags: html, css

[image]

Why is it that when i make an image a link it creates a little black line to the right of it?

Comment: It would help if we could see your code. Please post an example to jsFiddle that reproduces the issue. I suspect your images are in a `<a>` element and have you have `text-decoration: underline` set.

Comment: this is my code <a href = '##'>
                <img class = 'img' src = 'Icons/Agent.png' style = 'margin-top: 30px; border: none;'/>
            </a>

Comment: Please post your code to jsFiddle, not in the comments section.

Comment: heres the link http://jsfiddle.net/8rFBu/

Comment: you have one empty space in between img and </a> it's being underlined,  remove it :)

Answer (score 3):

It's a combination of two things. Your anchor has an underline, and your markup has whitespace. For instance, your HTML likely looks similar to this:

```
<a href="http://google.com">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100" />
</a>
```

That nicely formatted space contains whitepace characters that get rendered (and then, underlined from the anchor). Note that some of the other answers might remove the underline by using `text-decoration:none;`, but there is actually still a small space next to your images caused by the whitespace, which can cause trouble if you're trying to achieve a "pixel-perfect" rendering. To solve it, remove whitespace from in between your anchor tags or set the font-size to 0:

**Html fix (better):**

```
<a href="http://google.com"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100" /></a>
```

**Or, a css fix:**

```
a {
  /* Of course You'll want to better target this, since you won't want all anchors to be font-size:0 */
  font-size:0; /* Now that the font size is zero, whitespace won't show. */
  text0decoration:none; /* If you want to add this, you can, for good measure */
}
```

*Note: One caveat of the css fix is some older browsers ignore a font size of 0.*

Answer (score 1):

It's a weird artifact with links and images, that the `<a>`'s signature underline shows a little. If you have your code like

`<a href=...><img src= ... /></a>`

You can fix that line by disabling the default underlining behavior on `<a>` links with `<img>` tags inside. Just apply a class to all of the `<a>` links in question (like `<a class="img-link">`), then CSS:

```
a.img-link {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: It actually wouldn't happen if your html is like your snippet above.

Answer (score 0):

I have sorted it now, it was just a case of adding this to my css

```
a:link {
            text-decoration: none;
        }
```